# Algebraic Problem Fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Given the following fraction,

$$\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}(-2)^{n-1}$$

Is it correct that it simplifies to the following fraction,

$$(-1)^{n-1}n$$

I am in doubt because I have checked on three different places and they all gave different answer.

Comment: Just use $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$

$$\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}(-2)^{n-1}=\frac{n}{\cancel{2^{n-1}}}(-1)^{n-1} \cdot \cancel{2^{n-1}}=n\cdot (-1)^{n-1},$$

so yes.

Comment: How does the second step work?

Comment: @PloniAlmoni $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$, as Eugen noted in the comments above.

Comment: Oh I see. Very nice